# Compile batch script for c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I wrote the batch script below to compile cs code, but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
   @echo off
   %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
   csc.exe -target:exe *.cs
```

It opens the vcvarsall.bat but the last line does not work.

Comment: no error but nothing happens but opennig vs command prompt!

Comment: Uhm... shouldn't that be `csc.exe` instead?

Comment: Does that file exist? (I.e can you see in it Explorer, in that folder)

Comment: Take out the `@echo off` and try again - you'll see more output then.

Comment: @Christian.K: blimey, I didn't even spot that :-)

Comment: I guess you need to [call](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true) that vcvarsall batch file.

Comment: yes the file exist! after that bat file fires if i wrote manually :   csc.exe -target:exe *.cs it works fine but iam going to make it auto.

Comment: call and @echo off had no effect!

Comment: Try to specify full path to `*.cs`

Comment: @Reniuz There is no need to do so. *.cs is just ok.

Comment: I would try to specify full path to `csc.exe` and `*.cs` to ensure that it is not path related issue.

Comment: no a i mentioned before it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Make it works :

1- add this path to the system environments:

```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

2- change the .bat file to this:

```
   @echo off
   csc.exe -target:exe *.cs
```

.

Answer (score 1):

using `/k` will mean the `%comspec%` will remain in memory, until you **exit** the shell.
use `/c` and the batch file should continue after the other batch file has been run.

Also, you can use `call` in the place of `%comspec% /c`